# Why clang++3.5 failed to compile this code snippet while clang++3.6 could compile it?

Tags: gcc, g++, clang, llvm, clang++

This code snippet could not compile with clang++3.5, but could compile with clang++3.6 . And I search https://llvm.org/bugs/ , seems could not find any bugs about this. So why this code snippet could not compile in clang++3.5? g++ don't have this problem. Thank you in advance.

```
void F() {}

template <typename T>
class Option {
  public:

  Option(const T &) {}

  Option(T &&) {}

  template <typename U>
  Option(const U &) {}

};

class Fork {
  public:

  Fork(const Option<void (*)(void)>&) {}

};


int main() {
  Fork fork(F);
}
```

The compile error with clang++3.5

```
test.cpp:25:13: error: conversion from 'void ()' to 'const Option<void (*)()>' is ambiguous
  Fork fork(F);
            ^
test.cpp:7:3: note: candidate constructor
  Option(const T &) {}
  ^
test.cpp:9:3: note: candidate constructor
  Option(T &&) {}
  ^
test.cpp:12:3: note: candidate constructor [with U = void ()]
  Option(const U &) {}
  ^
1 error generated.
```

My clang++ version

```
clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the clang++ 3.5 compiler did not recognize any constructors in `Option` that matched type `void ()`. This may have been caused by const `Option<void (*)()>` being ambiguous.

Another site that you may find helpful:
[LLVM Open Source Lib](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/)

PS: I would like to post this as a comment, however I'm not at 50 rep.

Comment: But why 3.6 could recognize it? Seems don't have any tickets about this change in clang bugs website.